# Не сжимается сетка grid при уменьшении размера

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, grid

Ребятки, помогите пожалуйста. Сначала лучше откройте [**проект**](https:////problemon.github.io/1096051-device-31/) на главной странице слайдер, чтобы понимать о чем идет речь дальше.

Решил сделать адаптивный слайдер, но из-за `grid` который выше `.container` в `.main-page`, контейнер не сужается при изменении размера, хотя если убрать grid с `.main-page` все отлично работает, и такая ситуация со всеми элементами если им добавить `grid` и находятся выше `.container`
Проект залит на [**github**](https:////problemon.github.io/1096051-device-31/)

Если, нужна еще какая-либо информация по коду, напишите, хотя все выложено на [**github**](https:////problemon.github.io/1096051-device-31/)

Использую Chrome.

P.S. . Уже многое попробовал но не могу понять, как все сделать и оставить `grid`, так как он нужен для наложения, ну или подскажите может есть способ наложения лучше, но мне интересно почему себя так ведет `grid`.

Comment: Вопрос уже был задан, но поступило замечание, о недостатке информации.

Comment: для .carousel задайте width: 100vw

Comment: @EkaterinaRatatui, спасибо большое, только вот не понимаю как оно работает, но буду разбираться.

Answer (score 0):

Подсказали ответ, нужно `.main-page` на котором висит `grid` добавить свойство `grid-template-columns: 100%`